# Using lmer() with missing levels

Tags: missing-data, lme4-nlme, ancova

I believe I need to run a mixed-effects ANCOVA, and I am having difficulty, presumably, because I have missing data in one of my fixed effects or an incomplete design.

I have a random grouping variable, `abs.id`, two categorical variables, `leaf.species` and `cond.time`, and one continuous covariate, `day`.

`abs.id` includes up to four individuals

`leaf.species` has three levels: **map**, **syc**, and **oak**.

The problem arises in `cond.time`, which has 2 levels (**30** and **150**) for **syc** and **oak**, but only one level (**30**) for **map**.

I attempt to run the following model with `lmer()` (*lme4*) in R:

`lmer(mass ~ leaf.species*cond.time*day + (1| abs.id), data = growth.data)`

And receive an error.

So, generally, how do I deal with missing data in an `lmer()`?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: @Macro - I get `Error in mer_finalize(ans) : Downdated X'X is not positive definite, 7.`.  In additional Google, it's becoming clear that the error is a function of the incomplete design I have.  Any suggestions on handling this?

Comment: If $X'X$ is not positive definite then you either have more variables than you have observations or one (or more) of your predictors can be written as a linear combination of the others.

Comment: That's a lot of interactions there.  Try making it a bit more additive, variable by variable, starting with say `mass ~ leaf.species*day + cond.time  ...` (if that makes sense).  That process should both pin down the source of the numerical difficulty (though your analysis sounds right) and indirectly give you a better idea about the substantive implications of the analyses possible given your design.

Comment: That's an area SAS has advantage over R. Lmer, lme, glm and lm all have this limitation while in SAS handling missing labels is effortless.

Comment: @AlefSin, just replace missing values with `NA`s in `R` and you're done.

Comment: @AleSin - I had originally performed these analyses in JMP, which, I believe, runs similar to SAS, given that SAS owns it.  However, I'm redoing things for a manuscript, I no longer have access to JMP... and I like R...

Comment: Thanks, @ConjugatePrior.  I just tried this, and as expected, I receive the error when adding `leaf.species:cond.time`.  Given the incomplete design, there's no way to include the interaction, right? 

It seems that lmer() can't handle the interaction, but if I removed the random factor (abs.id) and run lm() things work.  How is the interaction to be interpreted there?

Comment: If I use `lme(method = "ML")`, and compare the `lm()` and `lme()` models with `anova()`, the random factor does not signficantly contribute to variance. Thus, I'd prefer use of lm(), which makes my above question more important.